# Finding the total area of different semi circles within a square.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, problem-solving, area

### Problem:

[image]

I have got so far that the radius of the small semi-circle + the radius of the larger semi circle is 2. I'm not sure how to proceed, however...

Any help?

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the larger semicircle have radius $r$. We see that, since it's angled at $45^\circ$,
$$r+\frac{\sqrt2}2r=2\implies r=\frac2{1+\sqrt2/2}=4(1-\sqrt2/2)$$
From here you should be able to work out the solution, since you know the sum of the semicircle radii.

Comment: thank you - however: please could you clarify where you got the value of  frac\{sqrt2}{2} - it might be me being thick, but unfortunately, I don't follow...

Comment: Draw a vertical segment through common center and parallel to side of square. Upper segment is radius of smaller semicircle. Lower segment is radius of larger semicircle.

Comment: @cosmo5 - but why is the lower segment equal to sqrt2/2 * the radius of the smaller semi circle

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel

Comment: But @ParclyTaxel - how do you know that the segment from the common centre to the south west point of the larger semi circle is equal to the vertical segment of the isosceles triangle?

Comment: Apologies @ParclyTaxel - what I meant was this: if you look at the question again, I have added another picture as an 'edit' - why exactly are the two black lines in the picture equal to each other? Can you prove it, or is it just intuition?

Comment: @vgupt The diagram is symmetric with respect to the descending diagonal of the square.

Comment: Ah, okay. Many thanks for your help - really appreciate it.